# Issue with add Multiple user account and SSH key using Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, permissions, centos

As per our requirement we provided our `devloper group: devs:r-x to /var/log/httpd` directory.
What is the best way to create a user account (in my case Dev User) in a Group using bash scrip, with the followings :
we have a devs group in our developer server, and now want to create a Linux function for 10 plus developers (user)

as a requirement If any of the '$1' directories exist, it would throw a notice to the executor. our developer will have their own key my plan was not to copy the key. we could pass the key in when this is executed, or have this generate the key and output it on completion.

**I have tried this code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

CREATE_USER_NAME="pi"

# Create account
echo "============= now create an account ============="
sudo useradd -s /usr/bin/fish -m $CREATE_USER_NAME
sudo usermod -aG devs $CREATE_USER_NAME
sudo passwd $CREATE_USER_NAME

if getent passwd "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi
mkdir -p /home/santosh/.ssh
chmod 0700 /home/santosh/.ssh
touch /home/santosh/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/santosh/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo chown -R santosh /var/www/html/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/httpd/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo chown -R santosh /var/log/httpd/santosh-dev.jove.com/
#
```

**Output I Received:**

```
[santosh@skb Desktop]$ ./user1.sh
============= now create an account =============
[sudo] password for santosh: 
useradd: user 'pi' already exists
Changing password for user pi.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
No, the user does not exist
```

what is the best advice here! I'm unable to figure it what is wrong here? can anyone guide me on it!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I basically found error while creating user in my "devs" group and Permission denied, Operation not permitted issue are coming whith ssh operation.

Comment: Seems like your script has some syntax errors. Try shellcheck (https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/) first to create a valid script.

Comment: Thanks , output as $ shellcheck myscript
No issues detected!
$